# Non-negative matrix factorization clusters

Tags: clustering, k-means, non-negative-matrix-factorization

NMF can be used for clustering i.e., $V=WH$ where $W$ represents cluster centers and $H$ represents the membership of samples. But can NMF alone cluster the samples? Can we get better clusters in NMF compared to k-means?

Let me know if I'm wrong. Any kind of reference would be helpful.